# Android SQL database organization

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-ndk

I am developing an Android native game, but I have problems with Data Storage.

For a better comprehension think it like as i am developing Clash of Clans, but with Native Andorid.

Now imagine I have to store all datas for Buildings, moneys, troups, ecc in my local phone DB.

I read some guides about SQLite for Android, but i don't really like it. It picks always a Cursor object and i have to create an "Helper" class for each table so I can convert the Cursor into the object I picked.

I want a library or anything else that allows you to do like windows phone c#:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath);
return conn.Query<TABLE_NAME>(SQL_QUERY);
//in this way i have a list of TABLE_NAME items without any casting or similar.
```

I learned `SugarORM` and it is really simple and intuitive, but it has no possibilities for ID usage(or at least really restricted) and a lot of other limitations.

And here is my question: is there a way to do it with SQLite without using cursor or with any other library, but still complete of all (or at least the most useful) functions?

Comment: primarily opinion-based ... "the easier way" is subjective

Comment: @Selvin ok, i'll change it you're right

Comment: @Selvin now should be better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this [link](http://www.developereconomics.com/five-popular-databases-for-mobile/) they explain the most five popular database and there characterstics

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i had time's problems. this helped me a lot. thanks you very much :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley your welcome